# Getting EF 6 from NuGet to install on F# projects

Tags: entity-framework, f#, nuget, visual-studio-2013

I can't seem to get Entity Framework 6.0.1 to install on a couple of F# projects I have. This is the error message I'm getting:

> Executing script file  'C:\source\payboard\PayboardWeb\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.1\tools\install.ps1'.
>   Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s): "Type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.FSharp.ProjectSystem.Automation.OAProject' in assembly 'FSharp.ProjectSystem.Base, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable."
>   At C:\source\payboard\PayboardWeb\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.1\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:633 char:5
>   +     $domain.SetData('project', $Project)
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SerializationException
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>     at System.Data.Entity.ConnectionFactoryConfig.InitializeEntityFrameworkCommand.Execute()
>     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)

It seems like there's an open bug for it on the EF6 forums (https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/891), but it hasn't gotten any love, so far as I can tell.

EF6 installs just fine on non-F# projects.

Any suggested workarounds?

Comment: I think you are pretty much out of luck until MS changes the  'Microsoft.VisualStudio.FSharp.ProjectSystem.Automation.OAProject' type to be serializable.  You could always submit this issue on the User Voice site for F# to see if that gets more love.  I doubt the EF team will be able to fix something in the base language.

Comment: If you read down in the comments of the following post from the EF team, someone from the team somewhat answers your question of when will EF support F#.  Not sure if it helps but it is at least official acknowledgement.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/10/31/ef6-performance-issues.aspx

Comment: I dug through @ScottWylie's link and found [work item 891](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/891) mentioned.  It appears that F# may work in the next version of EF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is getting unblocked in EF6.1. [Here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/891) is the workitem.

Note that the issue here is not EF itself but how the package is being added to your project. This makes me think that until EF6.1 is released you could probably work around this issue by getting the package unzipping it and adding references to EF6 assemblies manually to your project. Then you would have to update your config accordingly. (You could also create a temp C# project add the EF6 NuGet package which will give you the EntityFramework and EntityFramework.SqlServer dlls you could copy to your F# project and also a config file you could copy from which will be much easier than coming with the right configuration on your own)

Comment: I was trying to create a C# project that would do all the database things, but when I tried to query the database, the EF could not reach the MySQL server because the web.config was not configured properly, even though the app.config in that C# Project was just fine. This is what i'll try: transfer all the relevant EF configurations from app.config to web.config, but your solution seems to be worth trying. Here is your 50 points haha.

Comment: The NuGet package by default installs SqlServer provider and configures the app for SqlServer. If you want to use MySql you need to instal MySql provider and change the provider registration in the config file.

Comment: Yeah, I did that, but since the configuration file was in another project, the EF could not reach it.

Comment: The same error was fixed with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483671/ef-6-code-based-migration-exception-microsoft-visualstudio-data-tools-package-n