# EF 6 Code based migration exception: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package not serializable?

Tags: entity-framework

I have this configuration

```
internal sealed class Configuration :DbMigrationsConfiguration<IAS.Models.ApplicationDbContext> {
            public Configuration() {
                AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
                ContextKey = "IAS.Models.ApplicationDbContext";
            }

            protected override void Seed( IAS.Models.ApplicationDbContext context ) {
                var baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(File.ReadAllText(baseDir + "\\MyInsertScriptsql"));
        }
    }
```

when running upate-dataabase i get the following exception

> Excepción al llamar a "SetData" con los argumentos "2": "El tipo
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.Internal.OAProject' del
>   ensamblado 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Pa ckage,
>   Version=11.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' no
>   está marcado como serializable." En D:\Dev\Insuranse Advanced
>   Services\IAS\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:
>   611 Carácter: 20
>   +     $domain.SetData <<<< ('startUpProject', $startUpProject)
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException   System.NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como
>   instancia de un objeto.    en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetProjectTypes(Project
>   project, Int32 shellVersion)    en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.IsWebProject(Project
>   project)    en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.GetFacade(String
>   configurationTypeName, Boolean useContextWorkingDirectory)    en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c_*DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b*_0()
>   en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command) Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un
>   objeto.

Comment: Edit: i removed the code from Seed method and the exception is throwing anyway, whenever i run the command Update-Database, any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved, i opened the file 
..\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm and the line 611 states:

```
 $domain.SetData('startUpProject', $startUpProject)
```

I them after review my solution I found that the startup project was changed to the Database project, corrected this and the problem was gone.

Comment: Looks like their fallback technique is not fail-proof

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late solution however I thought it might help someone else. I had this problem and I changed the project to be the StartUp Project (Right click on the project and 'Set as Startup Project') and problem sorted.